# How to add a condition in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, if-statement, swipe

I want to add a condition like if someone click on Circle Avatar() image then it will be navigate to other page (suppose other page will USERPROFILE() page in my case) else someone swipe left or right then also it will be navigate to user profile() page
here is the code of ontap->

```
actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
            child: GestureDetector(

              onTap: () {Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserProfile()));},

              child: CircleAvatar(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
```

here is the code for onswipeleft->

```
onSwipeLeft: () {
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    PageTransition(
                        type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                        child: UserProfile(),
                        inheritTheme: true,
                        ctx: context),
                  );
                });
              },
```

Comment: are you using Named routes?

Comment: @classicdude7 no

Comment: so what is UserProfile() ?

Comment: @classicdude7 it is a page that print simple hello in center

Comment: You're using `setState()` wrong. Remove it from onSwipeLeft to start